# Using wget to download files to specific folders based on file extension

Tags: wget, file-management

I want to download `.jpg/.png/.tiff` files into my `~/Pictures/` folder, `.mkv/.avi/.mp4` in my `~/Videos` folder etc.

Is there anyway to do this?

the only solution I could come up with was using different aliases like :

```
alias vwget="wget -P ~/Videos/"
```

I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: Why don't you just download them all to a temp directory and then move them after downloading? Do this _have_ to happen in a single step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do this in two steps:

1. Download everything into one directory, preferably on the same file system as your `~/Pictures` and `~/Videos` directories so you don't need to use any more space.
2. Once they have downloaded, `cd` into the download directory and run these commands:

   ```
   mv *.jpg *.png *.tiff ~/Pictures
   mv *mkv *avi *mp4 ~/Videos
   ```

You might be able to make some complex script that detects the extension and issues a different wget command depending on it, but is it really worth it?

Comment: yea i was looking for a single step. less hassle this way. setup once use always :) but your answer does the job, maybe i will make it into a bash script that I will run every once in a while.